# Como iniciar uma função com o onclick?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Possuo um script que fica lendo um .log basicamente em tempo real e o mostra em tela, mas a questão é que ele inicia com o DOM, gostaria que ele iniciasse apenas a partir do click no botão, poderiam me ajudar?

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['ajax'])) {
    $sessionID = 'log'.$_GET['s'];
    session_id($sessionID);
    session_start();
    $handle = fopen('/\\cordas\instance-8480\log\server.log', 'r');
    if (isset($_SESSION['offset'])) {
        $data = stream_get_contents($handle, -1, $_SESSION['offset']);
        echo nl2br($data);
    } else {
        fseek($handle, 0, SEEK_END);
} 
  $_SESSION['offset'] = ftell($handle);
  exit();
}

  $randomSession = rand();
    $(document).ready(function( ) {
        $.repeat(1000, function() {
            $.get('automacao_tela.php?ajax&s=<?=$randomSession;?>', 
                function(data) {
                $('#tail').append(data);
            });
        });
    });

<form action="?automacao=ok" method="POST">
    <button type="submit" class="log-btn" >INICIAR PROCESSO</button>
</form>

<div id="tail" class="widget-stats-list-log">
    Starting up...
</div>
```

----- Adição de codigo----

```
<body>
    <div class="automacao-container">
        <div class="automacao-box">
            <div class="row">
                <div class=" col-sm-3">
                    <div class="stats-widget">
                        <div class="widget-header">
                            <h2>Automação</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="widget-stats-list" id="lerLog">
                            <form action="?automacao=ok" method="POST">
                                <button type="submit" class="log-btn">INICIAR PROCESSO</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="stats-widget" style="height: 495px;">
                        <div class="widget-header">
                            <h2>Parâmentros</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="widget-stats-list">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class=" col-sm-9">
                    <div class="stats-widget">
                        <div class="widget-header">
                            <h2>Log de Automação</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div id="tail" class="widget-stats-list-log">
                            Starting up...
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        $('#lerLog').on('click', function( ) {
            $.repeat(1000, function() {
                $.get('automacao_tela.php?ajax&s=<?=$randomSession;?>', 
                    function(data) {
                    $('#tail').append(data);
                });
            });
        });                               
  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matheus, você precisa criar um elemento que será clicado para chamar a função.

```
<div id='lerLog'>Ao clicar aqui a leitura do log acontecerá</div>
```

Ótimo! Feito isso coloque a função dessa maneira:

```
 $('#lerLog').on('click', function( ) {
        $.repeat(1000, function() {
            $.get('automacao_tela.php?ajax&s=<?=$randomSession;?>', 
                function(data) {
                $('#tail').append(data);
            });
        });
    });
```

**Mudança aplicada:**

```
$(document).ready()
```

Essa chamada quer dizer que toda vez que o documento estiver pronto para uso *(Quando a página termina de carregar completamente)* A função criada por você irá acontecer. leia um pouco mais sobre a [.ready()](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Então criamos o botão, definimos um id para ele e atribuímos a chamada `.on()` que trabalha com o elemento quando diferentes situações acontecem. Neste caso estamos usando o `'click'` *(onclick)*. Saiba mais sobre o [.on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

Lendo o seu código novamente, me deparei com o button com o texto INICIAR PROCESSO. Caso seja ele o responsável pela leitura log adicione: `id='lerLog'` para funcionar com a função.

Comment: Bom Dia Bsalvo, fiz tudo como comentou, coloquei o id no botão e introduzi o Onclick na função, só que agora ela não lê o log não inicia, e se eu tirar o onClick na função, ela funciona normalmente, já não sei mais oque fazer :/

Comment: Calma que vamos resolver, faça um teste e crie uma div para ser clicada. Esqueça o button e teste agora em um div. Não esqueça de me trazer o feedback!

Comment: Bom dia, ainda não funcionou mesmo com uma div, irei colocar meu código todo na resposta pode ser ? para que assim possa analisar melhor e dizer no que estou errando ?

Comment: Coloque ai, a função que eu disponibilizei já deveria estar funcionando

Comment: colocado como uma resposta abaixo

Comment: Matheus, é mehlro adicionar como edição na pergunta. Aqui é apenas para respostas mesmo.

Comment: Matheus a div com o id='lerLog'' precisa estar em cima do código da função... Primeiro a div depois o código

Comment: Bsalvo, coloquei como uma adição o código a qual me falou, mas da mesma forma ainda não funciona, só funciona se eu deixo como postei na pergunta acima da adição.

Comment: Huum. muito estranho.. Você está clicando em INICIAR PROCESSO? se for isso é provável que n funcione mesmo. Por favor apague aquele id='lerLog' que você colocou ali e adicione essa div <div id='lerLog'>Ao clicar aqui a leitura do log acontecerá</div> em qualquer lugar acima da função, só para fins de teste e me diga se funciona.

Comment: Agora com uma div separada funcionou o.O, não tenho a minima ideia do que pode ter acontecido. Será que não tem uma maneira de colocar atráves do botão ??

Comment: Matheus não existe a necessidade da tag <form> nessa situação, o type do botão está type='submit' isso quer dizer que ele trabalha diretamente com o form, você pode tentar mudar o type para type='button' e adicionar a id='lerLog' (não creio que isso irá funcionar) ou você também pode seguir meu conselho, e deletar esse form e esse botão e estilizar uma div para que fique da forma que você deseja. Se puder marcar minha resposta agradeço :)

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Bsalvo, infelizmente não posso tirar o Form pois o utilizo para uma outra função pegar o post dele de 'ok', mas vou fazer os testes aqui trocando o submit para button, e se nada funcionar vou pegar a div que funcionou e colocar atrás do botão invisivel. Te agradeço muito pela ajuda colega. Já marquei a resposta. Obrigado.

Comment: Só complementando, a sua ideia de trocar o "submit" para "button" funcionou, so preciso arrumar uma maneira de enviar o form agora kkk

Comment: Toda vez que acontece o envio do formulario o log também deve ser atualizado? Se for isso tenho a resposta rápida pra você.

Comment: Isso mesmo, toda vez que eu envio o formulário, é gerado um .txt no servidor, e eu vou la e pego esse .txt, e mostro em tela o log em tempo real.

Comment: O meu botão executa o cmd que inicia um arquivo .bat, que gera esse txt, e mostra ele em tela.

Comment: Matheus tem alguma outra forma que possamos conversar? Não é muito bom estender tanto o assunto nos comentários da resposta para não atrapalhar futuros leitores.

Comment: Aqui funciona ?

Comment: manda email pra mim, matheusrd97@hotmail.com